# How to use Contact Us form package for Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

I am using this package from Atmosphere.

https://atmospherejs.com/scalloped/contact-form

But I am unable to get it emailing to my accounts

```
Meteor.settings.contactForm = {
  emailTo: 'karlson.lee09@gmail.com',
  emailSubject: function (params) {
    'Message from ' + params.name + ' via contact form'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a mail server configured? `scalloped:contact-form` requires the package email, which means you need an environment variable `MAIL_URL`. Email with Meteor is explained in detail [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/email).

There is an article about [Environment Variables in Meteor on Meteorpedia](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables) which explains how to set them. E.g:

```
export MAIL_URL="smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/"
meteor
```